# How to resize an image file on php?

Tags: php, image

I have an image file which is stored onto database as a blob (shown in the code). Once resized to 80*80(thumbnail) I need to store it onto some other database. I have resized and saved it as a file but I couldn't store the resized image onto database. How can I achieve this?

```
//resize image and save
include('MyImage.php');
$image = new MyImage();
$image->load($tmpName);
$image->resize(80,80);
$image->save('thumbnail.jpg');


//storing original image onto database
if(isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0)
{
 $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
 $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
 $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
 $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];

 $fp      = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
 $content = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
 $content = addslashes($content);
 fclose($fp);

 if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
  {
    $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
  }

 $query = "INSERT INTO image_tbl (name, size, type, content )".
           "VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content')";
 mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed'); 
}
```

Comment: From someone who used to store images in database, I don't think this is a good idea.

Comment: 1. total lack of sql injection protection (and no, addslashes is NOT protection). 2. total lack of verification of upload's success. 3. apparent lack of awareness of 'file_get_contents()'. 4. Using variables ($tmpname) before it's defined.

Comment: @anpel Are you saying storing images on a database is not a good idea?

Comment: @MrGhimire, even though it looks like a good idea, it is not. What I've found useful when dealing with images, is save the image as a file with a random filename (say md5 of a random number), and then save the PATH to the image in the database, alongside the image information, title, caption etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct question to your answer is

```
//This goes after the frist block, after "$image->save('thumbnail.jpg');"

$fileSize=filesize('thumbnail.jpg')
$fp      = fopen('thumbnail.jpg', 'rb');
$content = fread($fp, $fileSize);
$content = addslashes($content);
fclose($fp);

$query = "INSERT INTO image_tbl (name, size, type, content )".
           "VALUES ('thumbnail.jpg', '$fileSize', 'image/jpeg', '$content')";
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
```

You might recognize some elements of that code :-)

But believe me, you do not want this:

- Storing BLOBs in the DB, that **the DB doesn't understand** is a bad idea
- using strings and addslashes to achieve it, is very close to the worst case possible: You read the image into a string consisting of ca 50% unprintables, backslash it, transport it to the DB, where it is unbackslashed and parsed. Use prepared statements with parameters (if you really want to save the image in the DB)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$file = $path_you_saved_image."/".$your_image_name;
$handle = fopen( $file , "rb" );
$img = fread($handle , filesize($file) );
$img = base64_encode($img);
$query = "insert into images (image) values ('$img')";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

you code suggests that you have saved the resized image. Now open this resized image 'thumbnail.jpg' and process it, encode it and save it.